# C++ linked list stack using pointers

Tags: c++, list, pointers, stack

So I have a stack with the typical Push and Pop functions that it allows. I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how it all actually works code-wise. I saw this post here,
[Picture/Diagram in the best answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065607/c-stack-pop-function-with-singly-linked-list) that shows how the list is "pushed" down and you point at the newest element. I have a

```
node* stack;
```

which is hooked to a struct "node"

```
struct node
{
    ItemType data;
    node* next;
};
```

How do I incorporate a push and pull with a "node* next;" ? The hard part to wrap my head around is how I'm going to actually do it. I know it initially points at null, and then if I were to push a 2,4,6 it would be 6,4,2,#. Grasping how to actually do it with pointers in a linked list throws me for a loop. I can do it without pointers but the pointers are what get me. Thank you for any help, I really wanna work through this. I'm here to comment back too quickly. Thanks!

EDIT 1:
solved - my push is working

EDIT 2:
I'm trying to pop now. Would that mean I have to just aim my pointer at the next value? What do I do to the old top node? delete it since I new'd it?

Comment: "So I have a stack with the typical Push and Pop functions that it allows" - sounds like you *don't* have that. Have you studied memory allocation as well as this particular data structure? Are you familiar with linked lists?

Comment: @crashmstr sorry, I mean I understand it without pointers. Working with pointers I have a hard time understanding it

Comment: Stacks add and remove from one end. So the "head" node changes on a push or pop.

Comment: @crashmstr Okay so I can add my new element at the end with the node* next, but I don't get how I can move backwards if I wanted to pop. There's no node previous, only a node next.

Comment: Don't add at the "back" end. A "push" adds a new `node` that then points to the old head of the stack (add/remove from the "front").

Comment: @crashmstr So I create a new node with whatever I'm going to insert, and it's node* next will point at my old stack. So continuing to do this, my stack will be with the newest at the "top" and the first item pushed in would be further away, right?

Comment: Yes, that is the simplest way to do it.

Comment: @crashmstr Okay, thank you. I've been having trouble wrapping around how it worked. I think I got it, I'm not 100% sure but I'll give it a go. Thank you!

Comment: @crashmstr added edit #1 to my post, still confused on how it works :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a C question.

Functions `push` can be defined in C++ the following way

```
void push( node * &stack, const ItemType &item )
{
    node *tmp = new node { item. stack };
    stack = tmp;
}
```

in C it can look like

```
int push( struct node * *stack, const ItemType *item )
{
    node *tmp = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );

    if ( tmp )
    {
        tmp->data = *item;
        tmp->next = *stack;

        *stack = tmp;
    }

    return tmp != NULL;
}
```

EDIT: After you edited your post I also edited my post.
It seems that pointer stack is a data member of class StackClass. In this case the member function can look like

```
void StackClass::Push( ItemType newItem ) 
// I would declare the parameter as const ItemType &newItem 
{ 
    node* temp = new node;
    temp->data = newItem;
    temp->next = stack;

    stack = temp;
}
```

Comment: Hello. My teacher provided us with a small skeleton in which our push method is a void function with only one parameter, which is the ItemType newItem. I have included the code I wrote in my edit #1 in my post up above, if you wouldn't mind checking it out. Thank you!

Comment: Yup, that's what I came up with. I know I kept changing what I was writing but I appreciate you sticking with me. I'm currently working on my pop but that wasn't originally asked. I marked your answer correct. Thank you!